# How do I display two rows from sql side-by-side using php?

Tags: php, sql

My code below displays 10 entries, but it displays it in 10 rows and 1 column. I would like for it to display 10 entries, but in 2 columns and 5 rows. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

`< ?php
        mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());`

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Members LIMIT 0, 10") 
or die(mysql_error());  

echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {


if ($row['Approved']=='No')
{
    continue;
}
else{

    echo '<td>';
echo "ID Number: ".$row['id'];
echo "<br/>";
    echo '<a href="original/'.sha1($row['Username']).'.jpg"><img src="'.$row['Pic'].'"></a>';
    echo "<br/>";
    echo '<hr>';
    echo '<tr>';

}
}
echo '</table>'
```

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die(mysql_error()); mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Members LIMIT 0, 10") or die(mysql_error());  

$i = 1;  //The following logic only works if $i starts at '1'.
$numofcols = 2; //Represents the number of columns you want in the table.

echo '<table>'; //Open table.

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

  if ($row['Approved']=='No'){
    continue;
  }
  else{

    //If it's the beginning of a row...
    if( $i % $numofcols == 1 ){
      echo '<tr>'; //Open row
    }


    //Table Cell.
    echo '<td>'; //Open Cell
    echo 'ID Number: '.$row['id'];
    echo '<br/> <a href="original/'.sha1($row['Username']).'.jpg"><img src="'.$row['Pic'].'"></a> <br/>';
    echo '</td>'; //Close Cell

    //If we have already placed enough cells, close this row.
    if( $i % $numofcols == 0) {
      echo '</tr>'; //Close Row.
    }

    //Now that we've made a table-cell, lets increment our counter.
    $i = $i + 1;

  }
}

//So we make sure to close our rows if there are any orphaned cells
if( ($i % $numofcols) > 0){
 echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>' //Close Table
?>
```

Please note that the mod logic will only work if the starting value of $i is '1'.
This code will create a table with 2 columns.

Comment: This works with no modification on my part. Thanks! How would I get it for 3 columns, actually?

Comment: Change the `$i % 2` to `$i % 3` about the `echo '</tr>'`.    I've edited my code to illustrate this a bit more.  Let me know if you have anymore questions.

Comment: Err, sorry, I forgot about opening the TR... Let me edit my code for better standard... 1 second.

Comment: @Reevas K made it so you can change the variable `$numofcols` to however many columns you want. Code should work fine now.

Comment: It's not working. The first, third, fifth, & seventh row have two columns, but the even numbered rows have 1 column

Comment: Sorry that I gave you bunk code. ::shame:: Does your name keep changing? I swear I'm going nuts >_> I assume you used my most recent code... I'll take a look and return to you with an update.

Comment: Ok thanks. And yes, sorry-- I can't decide what to make my name, haha.

Comment: HAHA. Man you were making me think I was disturbed. Haha. Can you show me the output of your code?

Comment: Sorry! haha. I'm on localhost but give me a second and I'll upload it to the live website.

Comment: Did you get a chance to view the website? I deleted the link.. let me know and I will repost if necessary.

Comment: Think I know the problem. I have moved where I increment our counter. Give it a try. :)

Comment: You're welcome! I've also added at the end an if-statement to close the ROW incase it doesn't get closed in the loop.  For example, in the loop, it'll only close a row if it reaches the end of the row. If the loop ends and we haven't reached the end of the row, we close it.

Comment: @MYH You're welcome again. Let me know if you have any questions on the techniques used here or anything...

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but basically you can call $row = mysql_fetch_array() in the loop as well to grab another row.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";

    echo "ID Number: ".$row['id'];
    echo "<br/>";
    echo '<a href="original/'.sha1($row['Username']).'.jpg"><img src="'.$row['Pic'].'"></a>';
    echo "<br/>";
    echo '<hr>';

    echo "</td>";

    $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
    if($row)
    {
        echo "ID Number: ".$row['id'];
        echo "<br/>";
        echo '<a href="original/'.sha1($row['Username']).'.jpg"><img src="'.$row['Pic'].'"></a>';
        echo "<br/>";
        echo '<hr>';
    }
    else
    {
        // Empty cell
        echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
    }

    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use modulo for echo "< tr>"

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Members LIMIT 0, 10") 
or die(mysql_error());  

$i = 0;

echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {


if ($row['Approved']=='No')
{
    continue;
}
else{

    echo '<td>';
echo "ID Number: ".$row['id'];
echo "<br/>";
    echo '<a href="original/'.sha1($row['Username']).'.jpg"><img src="'.$row['Pic'].'"></a>';
    echo "<br/>";
    echo '<hr>';
  if ($i % 5)
    echo '</tr>';
$i++;
}
echo '</table>'
```

Comment: Thanks much for your response. I put that in my code and it only made two of my entries display on the same row, the other 8 entries are still displaying on their own row?

Comment: replace echo '</tr>' by 
echo '</td></tr><td>';

Comment: I don't see how this code can make multiple rows if it only opens the <tr> tag once.

Comment: I had to add this:
        if ($i == 2)
        echo '</td></tr>';
        if ($i == 5)
        echo '</td></tr>';
        if ($i == 8)
        echo '</td></tr>';